# Mixed animate and inanimate?

Tags: числительные

According to the sources I've checked, only numbers from 1 to 4 have an animate ending (meaning that the accusative case will be the same as the genitive, endingwise). Numbers from 5 upward will have a common accusative for both animate and inanimate nouns.

However, in compound numerals, all components decline... what if I want to decline a number like 21, 22?

Since 1 and 2 also have an agreement in gender, will 1 and 2 decline as animate numerals, whereas "20" declines the usual way?

Example: What would be an animate accusative of **двадцать одна** (admitting that the agreement in gender happens)? **Двадцать одну**?

And **двадцать один**? Does it become **двадцать одного**?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it does become **двадцать одну** and **двадцать одного**. Would you be able to provide some example of complete sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **двадцать одна** becomes **двадцать одну** in the accusative and **двадцать один** will be either **двадцать одного** if it qualifies an animate noun or **двадцать один** if inanimate:

- Компания приняла на работу **двадцать одного** человека.
- Компания приобрела **двадцать один** компьютер.

With 22, 23 and 24 the inanimate pattern is more preferable:

- Компания приняла на работу **двадцать два** человека (less preferably: **двадцать двух** человек).
- Компания приобрела **двадцать два** компьютера.

Animacy, gender *and number* are dictated by the noun. Yes, you can say 'one' in plural:

- Купи **одни** ножницы. = Buy one pair of scissors.
- Он не курит уже **двадцать одни** сутки.

Unfortunately, there is no grammatically acceptable way of saying **22 сутки** (or 23, or 24). 25 and up are OK: **двадцать пять суток.**

Comment: practically speaking i guess **двадцать двух человек** would unlikely be ever used being replaced with **двадцать два человека** effectively falling back on the inanimate pattern simply because **двадцать** doesn't inflect and creates discordance

Comment: "двадцать одни сутки" is translated as "twenty and something days"?

Can't we say 22 сутка? As far as I know, 2/3/4 demand the genitive singular.

Comment: You should just change the sentence Он не курит  "в течение двадцати двух /трех/четырех суток"

Comment: @swrutra to me **двадцать трое суток** sounds palatable, not so much **двое** or **четверо**, but on the other hand... in colloquial usage they would do as well